# Defining a method that checks the existence of a variable

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to define a method `a?` which returns `true` when `a` exists, and returns `false` when `a` is not defined?

The following code doesn't work, because when `defined? a` got executed, variable `a` is outside of its scope.

```
a = 123

def a?
    if defined? a
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

puts a? # false
```

Is it possible to make the last line of my code return `true`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In ruby, the keyword `def` acts a scope gate, so you lose access to local variables that are defined outside of the method definition. Alternatively, you can define methods using a block, allowing you access to variables defined outside of the method definition.

```
a = '123'

define_method 'a?' do 
  defined? a
end
```

For more information on this, I highly recommend reading through the first section of Metaprogramming Ruby

Comment: Suppose `a` is not defined when you create the method. `a?` will now return `nil`. Now set `a` to "123" (or any value) and again execute `a?`. It will still return nil. That's because you created the method by executing `define_method 'a?' { nil }`. If `a` had been defined (to equal anything) you would have executed `define_method 'a?' { "local-variable" }`. See, for example, [this description](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html) of the keyword `defined?`. The downvote is mine.

Comment: Ah i  didn't realize it behaved this way. Thanks, I've learnt something new, and I agree that this shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: @SamFarmer, I choose your answer because I modified your code as 

`define_method 'a?' do
    if defined? a 
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end`

I didn't entirely follow the code you wrote.

Comment: I pasted my code in [gist](https://gist.github.com/lyenliang/c63068a7e1a9d849f04d40968e950d2c)

Comment: Try defining a after the method definition, and the method will return false.

Comment: lyen, if Sam's code won't work why would you expect your modification to work? The only difference is that you return `true` where Sam returns a truthy value and you return `false` where Sam returns a falsy value, `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Local variables are called "local variables" because they are local to the scope they are defined in. They *by definition* do not exist in other scopes.

What you *can* do, is re-ify the local scope as a [`Binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html) object by calling [`Kernel#binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-binding), and then check whether the local variable is defined in that `Binding` using the [`Binding#local_variable_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_defined-3F) method:

```
def a?(binding)
  binding.local_variable_defined?(:a)
end

a?(binding)
# => false

a = 42 if false

a?(binding)
# => true

a
# => nil
```

Or, more general:

```
def local_variable_defined?(name, binding)
  binding.local_variable_defined?(name)
end

local_variable_defined?(:a, binding)
# => false

a = 42 if false

local_variable_defined?(:a, binding)
# => true

a
# => nil
```

Comment: lyen. I'm perplexed. You selected an answer that purports (incorrectly) to do what you want to do, yet Jörg has explained why that is not possible.

Comment: I chose SamFarmer's answer because I modified his code like [this](https://gist.github.com/lyenliang/c63068a7e1a9d849f04d40968e950d2c). I didn't entirely follow his code.

Answer (score 0):

Defined itself return nil or true based on the existence of the given variable/object.

You should use `defined?` method directly instead use another method like this :

```
if defined?a 
    puts  "defined"
else 
    puts "not defined"
end 
a = 10

if  defined?a 
    puts "defined a: #{a}"
else
    puts "not defined"
end
```

Output:

```
not defined
defined a: 10
```

Comment: Perhaps so, but you have not answered the question or explained why the OP cannot do what he or she wants to do.